# Can setuptools / setup.py depend on a directory?

Tags: python, directory, setuptools

I am using a library I control. I would quite like to include this library and its dependencies in an app that uses setup.py. And would prefer not to go through git of pypi or my own package repository.

Would it be possible to point the app's `setup.py` at a directory where that directory has its own `setup.py` using `install_requires`? It isn't discussed in the [setuptools document](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html) - but I'm suspicious that this documentation is written for discoverability rather than completeness - as the cool kids do noweredays. I seem to remember doing this with `requirements.txt` before but I am trying to use raw `setup.py` here.

Here is a diagram of the file structure:

```
/library # the library is guaranteed to be at /library - docker
   library.py
   setup.py
/app
   # this uses library
   setup.py() <- I want this to install library from /library
   app.py
```

Comment: pip install -e directoryname (heading out so if you need more, it might be a day or two)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I want to put this in `setup.py` (using `install_requires`) if possible. I also need to resolve dependencies between my library and the othe dependencies of the apps `setup.py`. I know that `-e /dir` works in `requirements.txt` - which is what I've done before. I've clarified the question.

Comment: so it's a module inside a module and you want them both installed from the top level setup file. Is that anything like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197347/setup-py-inside-installed-module

Comment: @KennyOstrom Well it's an app that uses a library that I don't want to install "properly" (i.e. using pypi or git) but innstead want to be at a known location on my machine like `/library`.

Comment: Okay, now I'm confused. It's in the folder already, so it's in your module already. If you do not want to install it as a separate module, you don't have to do anything. Maybe your question should include a little more of the layout?

Comment: Yeah... it appears so. Let me draw a diagram. There are specifics about docker containers that I'm hiding because they potentially distract from the question and encourage people to declare this an XY problem - which is why everything isn't in directory.

Comment: I set up a similar layout and didn't find a quick solution yesterday, but I did note that using setup is deprecated. This would be a lot easier with a requirements file.

Comment: I don't  think `setup` is exactly deprecated and setuptools certainly  isn't (since more or or less have pip = setuptools = setup) People want you to use `pip install .` [instead](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html) of `setup.py install .`.  There's also [pyproject.toml](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html).  Yeah, this is supported in requirements   (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064426/when-would-the-e-editable-option-be-useful-with-pip-install)). My code using setuptools tho...